# How U.S. News college ranking works

Tags: regression, ranking

I am interested in the model/algorithm that they use to evaluate college ranking. Any ideas? Regression or simply weighting system

Comment: The [top Google hit](http://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/how-us-news-calculated-the-rankings) links to the official account of the algorithm.  What part of this do you need explained?

Comment: @whuber: I think they forget to add the "*university external affairs office that has the best connections*" factor but otherwise yeah, that ranking seems pretty legit otherwise.

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. I guess I have a couple questions. I understand there are 7 indicators, and multiple sub-indicators. Each indicators and sub-indicators have different weight/or percentage. My first question is after they collect all the data, do they normalize/standardize each sub-indicator variables, so that they all have same scale?

Comment: @whuber, second, let's assume that retention (worth 20%) has two sub-indicators "A" (55%) and "B" (45%). A=0.75, B=2.75 after both been standardized. Then what would you do, 0.75*.55+2.75*.45=retention score?

Comment: @Jing simply scaling the data does not matter a lot in the end as long as it is consistent among all universities. Given that the full grades are $X$ you just look "how close" to $X$ a particular university is in a particular subfield and you allocate the points accordingly. FWIW, here is the [Times World University rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Higher_Education_World_University_Rankings#Criteria_and_weighting). Times H.E. ranking explicitly $z$-scores the variables recorded .

Comment: @usεr11852 but there are hundreds of colleges, how do you break ties?

Comment: @usεr11852 when you said comparing a particular schoo's score to the full score X. do you mean by (school's score - full score) / (standard deviation)?

Comment: @usεr11852 TIMES HE use Z scores. do they use Z scores only for the final total score? or you could also apply to individual fields?

Comment: 1. Most of the time you won't have ties because you added up many different factors. Ties are very uncommon; even if they exist you just report them. That's why in some cases they even given ranges. 2. No, I mean let's say that the best school get has a score in aspect $A$ of $X= 145$ (totally random number I came up just now). That school gets 100% in that aspect $A$. That's all. 3. Please read the link provided; it says they standardized the individual scores.

Answer (score 2):

WHuber's comment is apt. However, for a deeper, more qualitative examination of how the rankings work as well as the influence they wield, read Malcolm Gladwell's takedown, *The Order of Things*, in this 2011 *New Yorker* article:

http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2011/02/14/the-order-of-things

Among the key points made are: one, while the methodology has a patina of rigor there are multiple, equivalent ways to rank the information, two, there is no real "ground truth" against which to validate the results and, three, the resulting rankings are based in large part on trivial numeric differences out to several decimal places.